# how to use one element to fire a click (one after another) if a condition is meet?

Tags: jquery

Hello mate i have a problem.i have a click event that show() an initially hidden div when clicked. the opened div has an input form

```
$(".coll-menu-footer input.menu-btn").click(function(e) {
    $("div.new-coll").show();})
});
```

i want to use the same baton element to submit only when the div that it displays is open.

To make the question simple to understand, one element, same event, different action at every fireup.

first click show a hidden div, second click submits the input data. how is this possible mates.

Answer (score 0):

Several possible ways to go:

1. Use jQuery's `.toggle()` to automatically apply an alternate action on each click.
2. In your event handler, examine the state of the page (open/closed) and decide what action to take based on that.
3. After the first click, deinstall the first event handler, install a different one that carries out a different action, and so on for third, fourth, etc...
4. Keep a counter for the number of clicks and in your single event handler, look at the counter and decide which action to take.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to determine if the div is still hidden. If its still hidden, show it. If it is not hidden, perform your submission.

```
$(".coll-menu-footer input.menu-btn").click(function(e) {
     if($("div.new-coll").is(":visible"))
     {
         //perform your submission code
     }
     else
     {
         $("div.new-coll").show();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two states of your button, the first shows the hidden div and the second submit the form.

```
$(".coll-menu-footer").on('click', 'input.menu-btn:not(.clicked)', function(e) {
    $("div.new-coll").show();
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});

$(".coll-menu-footer").on('click', 'input.menu-btn.clicked', function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    // submit and other code here
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vhbWw/)